How to recover the photos from MacBook hard disk that was recovered from a data service that provided me with RAR compressed archive files?
I had an Intel CPU MacBook Pro (already sold).
When I went to sell it as a 2nd hand computer, I found the hard disk doesn't work.
So I found a professional data recovery company to check the hard disk. After few days, they give me an SSD copy of what they recovered.
It shows every folder compressed as RAR format:

Table of the folder contents (pictured above) here:



Name
Date modified
Type
Size




Applications.rar
2022/6/3 19:59
Compressed Archive Folder
3,067,589 KB


Library.rar
2022/6/3 19:59
Compressed Archive Folder
3,989,603 KB


private.rar
2022/6/3 19:59
Compressed Archive Folder
5,152,238 KB


System.rar
2022/6/3 19:59
Compressed Archive Folder
2,805,820 KB


Users.rar
2022/6/4 7:10
Compressed Archive Folder
349,449,495 KB



I remember I backed up my iPhone on this hard disk as well. How I can find the iPhone photos backup?

Your question doesn’t specify it, but what version of macOS are you on now? What version of macOS was the data on originally? This procedure assumes you are on a macOS Sonoma (14.4.1) or something similar and modern.

Based on your screenshot, you would need to expand the Users.rar archive and look inside of it for your your user directory and within that directory that should be named Pictures/ and within that directory should be a file named Photos Library.photoslibrary. Recover that.
Once recovered, copy it onto your new Mac. Rename the file in your Mac’s  Pictures/ directory, copy the older Photos Library.photoslibrary into there and then launch the “Photos” app while holding onto the Option key.
You should be presented with a dialog box that looks like the screenshot picture below. Click “Choose Library” and select the old/recovered Photos Library.photoslibrary and et voilá! The photo library should be imported.

Just so you know, the Photos Library.photoslibrary file should not be explored for individual files. It contains tons of images and thumbnails that have crazy (hashed) filenames based on Apple’s logic. You’ll never decipher that stuff. Better to leave the archive alone in whatever format Apple has the photos stored in and import the stuff straight into the “Photos” app.

Thank you so much, it looks many photos inside, let me try, you are really expert!
